# Bind Volumes to Docker container in a pipeline job

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So, I have this pipeline job that builds completely inside a Docker container. The Docker image used is pulled from a local repository before build and has almost all the dependencies required to run my project.

The problem is I need an option to define volumes to bind mound from Host to container so that I can perform some analysis using a tool available on my Host system but not in the container.

Is there a way to do this from inside a Jenkinsfile (Pipeline script)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully clear if this is what you mean. But if it isn't. Let me know and I'll try to figure out.

What I understand of mounting from host to container is mounting the content of the Jenkins Workspace inside the container.

For example in this pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'xxx' } }

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '3', artifactNumToKeepStr: '1'))
    }

    stages {
        stage('add file') {
            steps {
                sh 'touch myfile.txt'
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'lvthillo/aws-cli'
                    args '-v $WORKSPACE:/project'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
                sh 'aws --version'
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

In the first stage I just add a file to the workspace. just in Jenkins. Nothing with Docker.

In the second stage I start a docker container which contains the aws CLI (this is not installed on our jenkins slaves). We will start the container and mount the workspace inside the `/project` folder of my container. Now I can execute AWS CLI command's and I have access to the text file. In a next stage (not in the pipeline) you can use the file again in a different container or jenkins slave itself.

Output:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (add file)
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ touch myfile.txt
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ ls
myfile.txt
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] getContext
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . lvthillo/aws-cli
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
FJ Arch Slave 7 does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 201:201 -v $WORKSPACE:/project -w ... lvthillo/aws-cli cat
$ docker top xx -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ ls
myfile.txt
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ aws --version
aws-cli/1.14.57 Python/2.7.14 Linux/4.9.78-1-lts botocore/1.9.10

[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 3652bf94e933cbc888def1eeaf89e1cf24554408f9e4421fabfd660012a53365
$ docker rm -f 3652bf94e933cbc888def1eeaf89e1cf24554408f9e4421fabfd660012a53365
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] cleanWs
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...[WS-CLEANUP] done
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

In your case you can mount your data in the container. Perform the stuff and in a later stage you can do your analysis on your code on your jenkins slave itself (without docker)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are under Linux, run the following code

```
docker run -it --rm -v /local_dir:/image_root_dir/mount_dir image_name
```

Here is some detail:
-it:  interactive terminal
--rm: remove container after exit the container
-v: volume or say mount your local directory to a volume.

Since the mount function will 'cover' the directory in your image, your should alway make a new directory under your images root directory.

Visit [Use bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to get more information.

ps:

run

```
sudo -s
```

and tpye the password before you run docker, that saves you a lot of time, since you don't have to type *sudo* in front of *docker* every time you run docker.

ps2:

suppose you have an image with a long name and the image ID is 5ed6274db6ce, you can simply run at least the first three digits, or more

```
docker run [options] 5ed
```

if you have more image have the same first three digits, you can use four or more. 
For example, you have following two images

```
REPOSITORY                         IMAGE ID
My_Image_with_very_long_name       5ed6274db6ce
My_Image_with_very_long_name2      5edc819f315e
```

you can simply run

```
docker run [options] 5ed6
```

to run the image My_Image_with_very_long_name.

Comment: although what you've suggested is the basis for the answer to my problem, I needed to know how to accomplish this when I had no information regarding the container. I am pulling the required image from a repository and then launching a container of that image from within a jenkinsfile so there was no way for me to know the container name and no provision to access it either. But yeah, the 'docker run -v  /local_dir/:/dir_on_image' command is the basis for all this. Thank you :)

Comment: This time I am not sure if I get your point. As I understand, maybe you can try --name new_container when you run a new container, and also you can accesse tell difference between your diffrent containers with container ID.

Comment: while running from a pipeline script it not possible to know the container ID. The script itself launches a random container of the pulled image. So to mount files, you don't actually know the container running. Basically everything should happen from the pipeline script.

Comment: I am a very fresh engineer, try to offer some help, but you see, for me still have to much to learn, and thanks for you patient, and sorry for not offering some useful information.

Comment: Actually what you offered was the correct answer. I was just looking for a way to get it done from a jenkins pipeline job :) and what you told is the actual basis for getting it right. I just said that so that in case you want to use it later, it'll be helpful :) thanks again